# find all word after word 'The" in a string Ruby

Tags: ruby

i have string like this

```
the horse and the hound and the horn that belonged to
```

how to get all word after 'the' word in a string? so it return like this

```
the horse, the hound, the horn
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`String#scan`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-scan) to get every "the" plus a whitespace followed by any word, and then [`join`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-join) those results:

```
"the horse and the hound and the horn that belonged to".scan(/\bthe \w+/).join(", ")
# "the horse, the hound, the horn"
```

Comment: Don't forget to put a `\b` before `the` in the regexp. `"breathe strongly and keep the pace"`

Comment: That's right @Fravadona, thanks for pointing that out.